# Is it possible to run closing animation in beforeDestroy hook?

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, gsap

I need to turn window smoothly before it will be destroyed, so that I've decided to write this code in beforeDestroy hook:

```
beforeDestroy () {
    TweenMax.to(this.$el, 0.6, {opacity: 0, height: 36})
}
```

However, it seems it doesn't wait until animation will be completed. Is it possible to do such things in beforeDestroy hook and how?

Comment: you should use vue `transitions` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks. It has an example using Velocity.js for custom javascript-based tweening (But ofcourse you can use any library other than velocity).

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag thanks, I didn't know about it.

Comment: sure, no problem :)